# Fetching username inside notebook in Databricks on high concurrency cluster?

Tags: databricks

While trying to fetch user data on high concurrency cluster, I am facing this issue. I am using the  command below  to fetch the user details

> dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().tags().apply('user')

Below is the error log, for the run. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o475.tags. Trace:
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public scala.collection.immutable.Map com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext.tags() is not whitelisted on class class com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext
    at py4j.security.WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.checkCall(WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.java:409)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:294)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can retrieve the information by using dbutils command:

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get()
```

Comment: Do you have a variation that can be used when a Notebook isn't available?

Answer (score 6):

I've been using this:

```
user_id = spark.sql('select current_user() as user').collect()[0]['user']
```

`current_user()` is a [documented SQL function](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/current_user.html) in Databricks

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code :

```
import json

# parse x:
y = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson() 
res = json.loads(y)
print(res['tags']['user'])
```

Note : Tested code
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is a gross work around, but I haven't found much better yet.

```py
import uuid
import shutil

# Create a unique temporary table location
tmpTable = f'/tmp/identifier/{uuid.uuid4()}'

# Write a single line to a delta format table.
spark.range(1).write.format('delta').save(tmpTable)

# Extract the username from the delta history 
username = spark.sql(f'DESCRIBE HISTORY delta.`{tmpTable}`').select('userName').collect()[0]['userName']

# Delete the temporary table
shutil.rmtree('/dbfs'+tmpTable)
```